# Adding values from multiple textFields

Tags: flutter

I have a list of tiles created with the 'tolist' method, each has a textField and controller.I want to get the sum of the values of all textFields into a variable and display as text.``

here is my code: `

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<String> myList = [
    'Materials',
    'Labour',
    'Plant and Equipment',
    'Subcontractor'
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
           
            ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              ExpansionTile(
                maintainState: true,
                title: Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: const [
                    Text('Test Code'),
                    Text('sum of all here',//sum of all values from each textfield here
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),),
                  ],
                ),
                children: myList.map((cost) {
                  return MyListTile(cost);
                }).toList(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

and MyListTile code :``

```
class MyListTile extends StatefulWidget {
  String title;
  MyListTile(this.title) : super();

  @override
  State<MyListTile> createState() => _MyListTileState();
}

class _MyListTileState extends State<MyListTile> {
  final TextEditingController _myController = TextEditingController();

  double materialCost = 0.0;
  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      subtitle: Row(
        children: [
          Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, bottom: 5, right: 0, left: 0),
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 35,
              width: 150,
              child: TextField(
                textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
                controller: _myController,
                showCursor: true,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                    disabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(),
                    filled: true,
                    labelText: 'Cost sum',
                    labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[500]),
                    hintText: 'Enter Cost',
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[500]),
                    suffixIcon: InkWell(
                      child: const Icon(
                        Icons.clear,
                      ),
                      onTap: () {
                        _myController.clear();
                      },
                    ),
                    // isCollapsed: true,
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15))),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(3),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.white10, width: 1),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)),
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  materialCost = double.parse(_myController.text);
                });
              },
              child: const Icon(
                Icons.done,
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
      trailing: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(3),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
            child: Text(
              materialCost.toString(),
              style: const TextStyle(
                  // color: mainColorShade,
                  fontSize: 14,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
      title: Text(
        widget.title,
      ),
    );
    ;
  }
}
```

I have tried to find a solution from allover the internet and I can not get any

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KN3TV.png)

Comment: Have a look how to return values from a widget with a callback function

Answer (score 0):

1. create textControllers for each of your textfields and pass it to your textfield inside your listTile:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  ...
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<String> myList = [
    'Materials',
    'Labour',
    'Plant and Equipment',
    'Subcontractor'
  ];

  // look here: list of controllers for your need change it for your liking
  List<TextEditingController> controllers = [
     TextEditingController(),
     TextEditingController(),
     TextEditingController(),
     TextEditingController(),
  ];
  
  // look here: local state to store your sum of textfields
  String sum = "";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    
    // look here: this will change sum value whenever either of the textfield's value changed
    for (var i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
      controllers[i].addListener(() {
        setState(() {
          sum = getSum(controllers);
        });
      });
    }
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
           
            ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              ExpansionTile(
                maintainState: true,
                title: Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Text('Test Code'),
                    // look here: this is your sum text
                    Text(sum,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),),
                  ],
                ),
                children: [
                   // look here: pass the controllers to your mylistTile widgets
                   for (var i = 0; i < myList.length; i++)
                        MyListTile(
                            title: cost,
                            controller: controllers[i],
                        ), 
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
  
  // if you want to change the sum result, change it here
  String getSum(List<TextEditingController> controllers) {
    return controllers.map((e) => "${e.text} ").toString();
  }
}
```

2. Don't forget to do this in your MyListTile widget, otherwise you can't pass the controllers

```
class MyListTile extends StatefulWidget {
  
  MyListTile({
    required this.title,
    required this.controller
  }) : super();

  final String title;
  final TextEditingController controller;

  @override
  State<MyListTile> createState() => _MyListTileState();
}
```

3. Use `widget.controller` in your MyListTile instead of _myController

```
class _MyListTileState extends State<MyListTile> {
  final TextEditingController _myController = TextEditingController();

  double materialCost = 0.0;
  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      subtitle: Row(
        children: [
          Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, bottom: 5, right: 0, left: 0),
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 35,
              width: 150,
              child: TextField(
                textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
                // look here:
                controller: widget.controller,
                ...
                  // rest of your code here
```

Comment: The for loop doesn't seem to work in the children of the Expansiontile .I had used to map method.toList to populate it.